# Cannot submit app to the google app marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I created an chrome web store entry here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forum/knpdbggaikbgjbgihfgefcjdabkhfgbp

And filled out the form for submission for google app marketplace:

https://docs.google.com/a/nimbusbase.com/forms/d/14QOb8PbSLKDgwIp8Zv-luoAAVurPXUqtzL0Hgikp3rk/viewform

This was over 1.5 month ago. Since then, I have not had any word about my app rejection or seen it in the google app marketplace.

I'm not sure what the process for app review is. Does no word ever back mean your app is rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if you don't hear anything back from us that is a good thing! However, in your case, it appears that you have not set up your manifest file correctly. You have failed to include the DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE container. Take a look at the documentation at:

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace

You'll find an example manifest file that you can model yours after.

Since the manifest file was never set up correctly, the application did not enter our review queue which is why you never heard anything about it.

Comment: ok thanks! I got it now. That was very helpful, I will amend the manifest and resubmit.

Comment: I submitted again about 10 days ago with the manifest fixed, and still haven't heard back, around how long is the review process and do we get an email if it's been approved? Thanks again

Comment: Hey I see that the app store now moved to the admin panel and it makes a lot more sense now. I see my app, ignore my previous message